# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSSortDescriptor *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSArray *

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am sorting my `NSSet` using :

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[[testSet.questions allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor]; // warning
```

But it causes warning :

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSSortDescriptor *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSArray *
```

Comment: Read the documentation, an array of NSSortDescriptors is expected!

Comment: @BaZinga are you getting rid from warning with my answer.

Comment: -1 Too localized.  A quick look at the docs explains everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a single descriptor where an array is expected, try this:

```
[testSet.questions allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should see this method. It requires you to pass an Array object to it, not a NSSortDescriptor object.

```
  [sortDescriptions sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:<#(NSArray *)#>]
```

so you have to create an array and put your NSSortDescriptor object in it. Try this

```
  NSArray *_sortArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:descriptor, nil];
  [testSet.questions allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:_sortArray];

  or

  [testSet.questions allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

see if it could help:)

Answer (score 1):

**NSSortDescriptor** should be passed in an array. So you have to create an array then add the  descriptor in the array. Now you should pass the array instead of **NSSortDescriptor**:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]
[[testSet.questions allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptorArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[[testSet.questions allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Hope this will help.